# What was the URL for the Ready Player One competition website?

Tags: ready-player-one

In the printed version of *[Ready Player One](http://readyplayerone.com)* lies an "easter egg" hidden in some misspellings from which readers can deduce the site where a competition took place.

I read the book last and then gave it away to a friend who was interested, so I cannot get back to it. Can anyone scan me that page or tell me where it is so that I can ask my friend to send me a photo? I've gotten really curious, so much that I'd read the book again, which I cannot do.

Comment: Are you referring to the url for the first gate from the contest last year?

Comment: @phantom42 Yes...

Comment: then there's this website, which is http://www.anoraksinvitation.com/

Comment: Sorry is this question from 2013 marked as a duplicate of a question asked in 2014?

Comment: Age and which came first isn't a measure of which should be marked as a dupe or not. However, the questions aren't dupes to begin with, so... whatever.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not quite a "misspelled url", so much as a hidden url found by searching for typos in the printed version of the book.

The URL for the first gate is:

> http://anoraksalmanac.com/